# How to restart my app in the activity that was running before system kills it android?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Users of my app running it most of the time in background.After a long period the system kills my app and when they try to get in to my app it starts all over again.How can I retrieve the last point of my app before it gets killed?

Comment: What do you mean by "last point"? Could you not just save the important information in a file in the `onDestroy` method and recall that information when the app is started again?

Answer (score 0):

Override `Activity.onPause()` and in there put some code that saves to a database or `SharedPreference` the current activity's class name. Then from your main activity read back from the database or `SharedPreference` and start the appropriate activity.

Comment: onDestroy() in not guaranteed to be called.  At any point after onPause() the app is killable *without* notice.  And of course an actual error will take it down at any point.

Comment: This will not work - the Android documentation says that onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called

Comment: Then override `onPause()`. Changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences for tasks like these.

In your onStop() function, set a flag in shared preferences like:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("killed", "yes");
```

In your onStart(), retrieve the preference and check it like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String flag = prefs.getString("killed", null);

if(flag!=null && flag.equals("yes")
{
//activity is resumed
}
else
{
//activity is started from scratch
}
```

for more info on shared preferences, see official docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

**This was on a similiar post called "Resume after App kill Android" [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776023/resume-after-app-kill-android)

The answer belongs to - Anup Cowkur**

Comment: onStop() and onDestroy() are not guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 0):

The only guarantee that you have is that **onPause() will be called** when the Activity goes into the background. Before Android kills your app, **there is no guarantee that onStop() or onDestroy() will be called**. What you can do is to write the state of your app, your settings, important data, etc., into either a SharedPreferences file or a database and retrieve this in onResume().